# Drupal hashing algorithm

Tags: api, drupal, hash

I am about to create an API that communicates with a drupal 7 generated database . So , one of the features is the login/authenticate function . So , to make this happen I had to deal first with password hashing mechanism . I analysed carefully the file "Includes/password.inc" and copied all functions into my API root . So , the good news is that I could generate hashed password that looks exactly the same as those generated by drupal , 55 characters long and begin with $S$ . The problem I am encountering concerns the authenticate method and to be exact the user_check_password that takes a plain text password and a user object and verifies if the hashing of the given plain-text password matches the hashing already stored in the database for that user . So , it returns always false (no match) even if the password is correct , except when I change the value of the hashing password ( stored already in the DB with drupal) with the value generated with my script , in this case the function returns true (match) if the password is correct . What do you think may cause this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to mind is: are you using the same "salt" (drupal_hash_salt) as defined on the settings.php file in Drupal?

Comment: I also thought that they use it in Password hashing , but lately  I realized that they use another salt key that gets generated with the function _password_generate_salt() .